# Can't use cordova-plugin-file on ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-file

I am trying to use ionic 4 and cordova-plugin-file to get files from phone but it trows an error;

When i do `console.log(cordova.file)` like in the doc it shows cordova does not have property 'file'.

When i do 
    `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);` it show 'requestFileSystem' not a property of window.

even if i do `window.cordova` it trow thesame error.

and unlike ionic 3 here if i add File to providers it trows an error as well

Please what is it i'm doing wrong?

Here is my ** home.page.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor(public platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                console.log(fileSystem)
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ionic 4 you should add '**ngx**' at the end of the import.

Like this,

`import {File} from '@ionic-native/file/ngx'`;

Make sure to add it to the **providers** list of your module file, and also inject it to the constructor of the class where ever you are using the plugin.

Reference https://ionicframework.com/docs/native